# Timezone offset in sqlite's strftime

Tags: sqlite, timezone, strftime

How do I express the timezone of a datetime with sqlite's `strformat`? Specifically, I want a timezone-(offset-)aware ISO8601 representation like `2018-10-23T19:58:33+02:00`.

The [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) claims that sqlite supports the *most common* options of C' [`strftime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html). Apparently, this does not include either `%z` or `%Z` in the format string, as the output is empty if I use one of them:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', datetime(1540317513, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'));
2018-10-23T19:58:33
sqlite> select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', datetime(1540317513, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'));

sqlite> select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z', datetime(1540317513, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'));

sqlite>
```

So how do I include the timezone in sqlite's string representation of a datetime?

Comment: *The format string supports the most common substitutions* `%Z` and `%z` are't ones it supports. The codes it does are in that documentation.

Comment: @Shawn Good point. Adapted the question.

Comment: Actually `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.Z');` would do the trick since the time is in UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do it at the application level, i.e, extract the times from the database as Unix timestamps and then convert to the format you want using the C strftime() function (or whatever its equivalent in the language you are using).

Comment: But when I extract the datetime as a Unix timestamp, I lose the timezone information, don't I? In my application, I need the correct timezone information as stored in the database.

Comment: @phihag: Only if you have entered your timestamps incorrectly in the database.  Remember, Unix timestamps *do not have* a timezone - they are absolute indications of time from a fixed starting point.  Therefore, when you convert them to an ASCII representation, that representation can differ depending on your local timezone, but the Unix epoch time is independent of that.